# Check a record + error message

Tags: php

When the user wants to fill the field nom_club , I wish to check each records. 
Namely no duplicate. I think my query is ok?

```
$sql_club = "SELECT * FROM clubs WHERE nom_club = '$nom_club' ";

    $resultat_club = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql_club);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($resultat_club) > 0){
            $club_erreur = "Ce Club existe déjà...";
    }
```

Now, I would like in the form, put a message (error).

My code is not good visibly ?

```
<tr> 
                <td>Nom du Club:</td>
                <input type="text" name="nom_club" value="<?php echo $nom_club;?>">
                <?php if (isset($club_erreur)): ?>
                    <span style="color: red;"><?php echo $club_erreur; ?></span>
                <?php endif ?>

            </tr>
```

Comment: i think this question maybe more suitable for [UX SE](https://ux.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I'd really suggest using PDO http://www.phptherightway.com/#pdo_extension and decoupling your php & html using templates: http://www.phptherightway.com/#templating

Also, are you sanitizing `$nom_club`?

Comment: Your query appears insecure.  I recommend mysqli's prepared statements with placeholders.  Please research this topic.

Comment: @Joe P; thak you for your help. Yes, I defined $nom_club = "";

Comment: @mickmackusa : ah ok I am going to search